# SQL Migrating old table to new table with an additional column

Tags: mysql, database

So im trying to migrate an old table to a new while maintaining compatibility, so my first guess would be to just map everything over by from example_A to example_B while inserting an old date.

Anyways, my question is there anything else I should do in order to maintain backward compatibility such using relations?

Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE example_A
(
  id INT
  price NUMERIC
  primary key (id)
)

CREATE TABLE example_B
(
  id INT
  price NUMERIC
  date DATE
  primary key (id, date)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most queries should work compatibly, they'll just ignore the new column. Here are some potential problems:

- Queries that use `SELECT *`. If the query involves a `JOIN` with another table that has a `date` column, the `date` column in the result will be ambiguous as to whether it refers to this table or the other table.
- If you join with a table that has a `date` column, and refer to that column without a table prefix, it will become a syntax error because of the ambiguous reference.
- `INSERT` statements that don't list specific columns will break, because the number of values will no longer match the number of columns.

You should also specify a default value for the new column, so that `INSERT` queries that don't fill it in will work.